# np.array of np.arrays into one n-dimensional array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a multiple .npy files and want to have them in one n-dimentional np.array

np.load(file) has shape (n, 3). There are m files, so result shape should be (m, n, 3)

Now i have this:

```
np.array([np.load(file) for file in h_files])

output:
array([array([[ 3.40040e+00, -1.48372e-02, -6.52934e-01],
              [ 3.37660e+00, -1.53226e-02, -5.28748e-01],
              [ 3.36828e+00, -1.58727e-02, -4.08290e-01],
              ...,
              [ 3.35563e+00, -2.34267e-03,  2.89650e-01],
              [ 3.35869e+00, -2.93101e-03,  1.74017e-01],
              [ 3.36274e+00, -3.52146e-03,  5.80292e-02]], dtype=float32),
       array([[ 3.40534   , -0.00772648, -0.653887  ],
              [ 3.37169   , -0.0082386 , -0.527966  ],
              [ 3.36334   , -0.00880522, -0.407682  ],
              ...,
```

What result i would like to have:

```
array(      [[[ 3.40040e+00, -1.48372e-02, -6.52934e-01],
              [ 3.37660e+00, -1.53226e-02, -5.28748e-01],
              [ 3.36828e+00, -1.58727e-02, -4.08290e-01],
              ...,
              [ 3.35563e+00, -2.34267e-03,  2.89650e-01],
              [ 3.35869e+00, -2.93101e-03,  1.74017e-01],
              [ 3.36274e+00, -3.52146e-03,  5.80292e-02]],
             [[ 3.40534   , -0.00772648, -0.653887  ],
              [ 3.37169   , -0.0082386 , -0.527966  ],
              [ 3.36334   , -0.00880522, -0.407682  ],
              ...,
```

Comment: Looks like you got a 1d object dtype array.  Did you get a 'ragged array' warning?  I suspect your arrays are not all `(n,3)` shaped.  You would get a (m,n,3) if they all matched.

Comment: n = 7000. They all shoud have the same shape. But yes, i have the warning. Concatenate helped to solve problem

Answer (score 0):

I have not checked it, but you could try the following:

```
np.array([np.load(file).tolist() for file in h_files])
```